# Entity Framework Core bulk update underlying collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Is there a known extension for Entity Framework Core that can do this bulk update as in this SqlRaw example?

```
dbc.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
            "UPDATE [Assembly] SET OnHold = @OnHold, UpdatedWith = @UpdatedWith, UpdatedAt = @UpdatedAt, UpdatedById = @UpdatedById FROM [Assembly] INNER JOIN Station ON [Assembly].StationID = Station.ID INNER JOIN Project ON Station.ProjectID = Project.ID WHERE Project.ID = @ProjectID",
            onHold, updatedWith, updatedAt, updatedById, projectID)
```

All the tables are related, i.e. Project -> Station -> Assembly, and I want to update some values for all assemblies that are under the same project with specific ProjectID, as shown in the above statement.

p.s. Extensions I have seen until know can do bulk update, but on the first table, not on the related tables on the main entity.

Models:

```
public partial class Assembly
{
    public Assembly()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public string UpdatedWith { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public bool OnHold { get; set; }

    public virtual Station Station { get; set; }
}

public partial class Station
{
    public Station()
    {
        Assemblies = new HashSet<Assembly>();            
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }   

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Assembly> Assemblies { get; set; }
}

public partial class Project
{
    public Project()
    {            
        Stations = new HashSet<Station>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Station> Stations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with SqlRaw?

Comment: Nothing, it works perfectly. I just want to know if it is possible to do the same with some sort of EF extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (disclaimer: I'm one of the creators)

Then you can do the following:

```cs
var updateQuery =
    from a in ctx.Assembly
    join s in ctx.Station on a.SationId equals s.ID
    join p in ctx.Project on s.ProjectId equals p.ID
    where p.ID == projectId
    select a;

var recordsAffected = await updateQuery
    .Set(a => a.OnHold, onHold)
    .Set(a => a.UpdatedWith, updatedWith)
    .Set(a => a.UpdatedAt, a => Sql.CurrentTimeStamp)
    .Set(a => a.UpdatedById, updatedById)
    .UpdateAsync();
```

If you have defined appropriate navigation properties, query can be simplified and joins can be removed.

```cs
var recordAffected = await ctx.Assembly
    .Where(a => a.Station.ProjectId == projectId)
    .Set(a => a.OnHold, onHold)
    .Set(a => a.UpdatedWith, updatedWith)
    .Set(a => a.UpdatedAt, a => Sql.CurrentTimeStamp)
    .Set(a => a.UpdatedById, updatedById)
    .UpdateAsync();
```

Comment: I will test it, and get Back with the result.

Comment: Navigation properties are properly defined.

Comment: I tested it, an it works as expected. Can you please explain to me how to simplify the query? The navigation properties are set.

Comment: Update question with Model.

Comment: I have updated the question with the models, as requested.

Comment: @mileski, updated answer with simple `Where`, which is obvious.

Comment: How can I display the generated sql code of this example? By default, it is not displayed in the Visual Studio output.

Answer (score 1):

The [`IQueryable.ToQueryString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.toquerystring?view=efcore-5.0) method introduced in Entity Framework Core 5.0 may help reduce/simplify the raw SQL used in your code. This method will generate SQL that can be included in a raw SQL query to perform a bulk update of records identified by that query.

For example:

```
var query =
    from a in dbc.Assembly
    join s in dbc.Station on a.StaionId equals s.Id
    join p in dbc.Project on s.ProjectId equals p.Id
    where p.Id == projectId
    select a.Id;

var sql = $@"
    UPDATE Assembly
    SET OnHold = {{0}}, UpdatedWith = {{1}}, UpdatedAt = {{2}}, UpdatedById = {{3}}
    WHERE Id IN ({query.ToQueryString()})
";

dbc.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sql, onHold, updatedWith, updatedAt, updatedById);
```

The major drawback of this approach is the use of raw SQL. However I don't know of any reasonable way to avoid that with current Entity Framework Core capabilities - you're stuck with this caveat, or the caveat of introducing a dependency on another library such as [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) as mentioned in another answer here.

If (when) the following issue is addressed in the future then we are likely to have a better answer to this question: [Bulk (i.e. set-based) CUD operations (without loading data into memory) #795](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/795)

Answer (score 1):

Just a little patience there will be the built-in `BulkUpdate()` as well as `BulkDelete` methods in EFCore which will be delivered in EFCore 7.0

```
context.Customers.Where(...).BulkDelete();
context.Customers.Where(...).BulkUpdate(c => new Customer { Age = c.Age + 1 });
context.Customers.Where(...).BulkUpdate(c => new { Age = c.Age + 1 });
```